# Calculate percent change on a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
                 Value        1lag 
Date                                                                     
2005-04-01  258.682029  214.382786 
2005-05-01  173.253998  258.682029
2005-06-01  244.432029  173.253998
2005-07-01  213.706019  244.432029
2005-08-01  213.670665  213.706019
```

Those are absolute values of two time series. However, I don't want those absolute values, I want the variations of them, so they get to look like this:

```
                 Value        1lag 
Date                                                                     
2005-04-01         NaN         NaN 
2005-05-01      0.3302     -0.2066
2005-06-01     -0.4108      0.3302
2005-07-01      0.1257     -0.4108
2005-08-01      0.0002      0.1257
```

Is there an easy command to do that? If not, what would be your suggestion to achieve that result?

Comment: @Alexander make this an answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can just use `pct_change()` on the dataframe.

```
>>> df.pct_change()
               Value      1lag
Date                          
2005-04-01       NaN       NaN
2005-05-01 -0.330243  0.206636
2005-06-01  0.410831 -0.330243
2005-07-01 -0.125704  0.410831
2005-08-01 -0.000165 -0.125704
```

Comparing the results above with yours, you would need to use `-df.pct_change()` if you want reverse the change as you have done.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
>>> 1 - df / df.shift(1)
               Value      1lag
Date                          
2005-04-01       NaN       NaN
2005-05-01  0.330243 -0.206636
2005-06-01 -0.410831  0.330243
2005-07-01  0.125704 -0.410831
2005-08-01  0.000165  0.125704
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replicate Alexander's response with the code below.  I am afraid Roman's response has the wrong sign

```
>>> (df-df.shift(1))/df.shift(1)
               Value      1lag
2011-01-31       NaN       NaN
2011-02-28 -0.330243  0.206636
2011-03-31  0.410831 -0.330243
2011-04-30 -0.125704  0.410831
2011-05-31 -0.000165 -0.125704
```